# How can I stop matplotlib from showing an extra year or month?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

For example, I have this array:

`ncdf1['level'].loc['2017':'2017']`

```
<xarray.DataArray 'level' (time: 246)>
array([302.52 , 302.42 , 302.3  , ..., 310.07 , 310.74 , 309.723])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01 2017-01-02 ... 2017-12-21
```

But when I try to plot it, I get an extra month (or year if try for multiple years):

`ncdat['level'].loc['2017':'2017'].plot(color='#1f78b4')`

How can I automatically make the plot from Jan-Dec?

[image: y]

### #

`ncdat`

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 4680)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2005-01-01 2005-01-02 ... 2019-05-09
Data variables:
    level    (time) float64 307.7 307.4 307.2 307.0 ... 300.4 301.3 303.2 303.0
    storage  (time) float64 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 ... 0.001 0.001 0.007 0.006
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont get this issue.

[image: Check the screenshot below]

What is ncdat? What datatype is it?

Can you add a screenshot of what ncdat looks like ?

Screenshot for xarray

[image]

Comment: It's an `xarray` dataframe. I have attached ncdat.

Comment: Still Cannot recreate the issue you are having. Check the screenshot i just added.